# c++ exception safety in constructor

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

What about following code

```
MyClass a(new Foo(), new Bar());
```

if "new Foo()" is successful, but "new Bar()" throws,  will Foo leak?

Is taking

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo>
```

or

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo>
```

as parameters, enough to prevent the leak?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if "new Foo()" is successful, but "new Bar()" throws, does Foo will leak?

Yes.

> Is taking [...] as parameters, enough to prevent the leak?

Not necessarily. It depends on how you pass the parameters. For instance, even supposed your class constructor looks like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo, std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar)
```

The following may still cause a leak:

```
MyClass a(std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()), std::unique_ptr<Bar>(new Bar())
```

That is because the compiler may is allowed to evaluate the above expressions in the following order:

1. Evaluate the expression `new Foo()`
2. Evaluate the expression `new Bar()`
3. Construct the `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` temporary from the result of 1.
4. Construct the `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` temporary from the result of 2.

If 2) throws an exception, you've lost your `Foo`.

However, it is possible to make this safe by using `std::make_unique<>()` (C++14 only) or `std::make_shared<>()`, like so:

```
MyClass a(std::make_unique<Foo>(), std::make_unique<Bar>());
```

Now no leak could possibly happen, because `std::make_unique<>()` (and `std::make_shared<>()`) immediately associate the object they create to the corresponding smart pointer, without these two operations (dynamic allocation and construction of the smart pointer) being interleaved with any other operation.

Comment: @DarioOO: The C++ Committee said that not including `make_unique` in the C++11 standard was because they merely forgot to. It is extremely simple to write compared to `make_shared`, so they figured out that programmer would write it themselves. I think they concentrated on `make_shared` that tries to improve performance compared to manual `shared_ptr` construction.

Comment: Yes, I thought the main advantage of make_shared was just performance improvement, but reading this answer there's much more than a simple performance increase.