# Methods called for object in c++

Tags: c++

What methods are called when we create an object of a class in c++ or what exactly happens when we create an object of a class.

Comment: Definitely constructor for one.

Comment: Create *how*? Variable on the stack? Global variable? Static variable? On the heap?

Comment: In a comment below, you indicate you were told there were 5 methods. You will need to quote more of the entire question if you want answers, because for the question you asked the answer is "The constructor". If the answer is "5 methods" then the question was more complex than the one you have posted.

Comment: no the person simply asked me that what are the functions which would get called when we will create an object of the class

Comment: Was he talking about a specific class that he'd demonstrated in previous examples?

Comment: no he didnt gave any example

Comment: Ok I answered, there are not exactly 5 methods/functions called (usually only 1/2 functions are called infact), but 5 different things may happens. Or maybe he was asking for more low-level stuff like how works stack at CPU level or including compiler functionalities like "parse" etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your class is called CMyClass.

```
#include "MyClass.h"

/* GLOBAL objects */
static CMyClass g_obj("foo"); // static makes this object global to this file. you can use it
                              // anywhere in this file. the object resides in the data segment 
                              // (not the heap or the stack). a string object is created prior
                              // to the constructor call.
int main(void) 
{
    ....
    if (theWorldEnds) 
    {
        /* STACK */
        CMyClass obj1; // this calls the constructor CMyClass(). It resides on the stack.
                      // this object will not exist beyond this "if" section

        CMyClass obj2("MyName"); // if you have a constructor CMyClass(string&), the compiler                 
                                // constructs an object with the string "MyName" before it calls 
                                // your constructor. so the functions called depend on which 
                                // signature of the constructor is called.

        /* HEAP */
        CMyClass *obj3 = new CMyClass(); // the object resides on the heap. the pointer obj3  
                                         // doesn't exist beyond the scope of the "if" section,  
                                         // but the object does exist! if you lose the pointer, 
                                         // you'll end up with a memory leak. "new" will call
                                         // functions to allocate memory. 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without additional information, you should assume that one and only one *member function* of the class itself is called, the constructor.

```
class CheesePizza {
public:
    CheesePizza() {}
};

CheesePizza barely; // will initialize by calling Foo::foo().
```

There are many cases in which additional *functions* might be called, for instance if you create a conversion scenario where a temporary object must be created, such as specifying a std::string argument and passing a const char* value.

```
    class DIYPizza {
        std::string m_toppings;
    public:
        DIYPizza(const std::string& toppings) : m_toppings(toppings) {}
    };

    DIYPizza dinner("all of the toppings");
```

This has to create a temporary std::string from the const char* argument, "all of the toppings". Then the DIYPizza::DIYPizza(std::string) operator can be passed this temporary (rvalue), and then subsequently we initialize m_str from it which invokes the std::string(const std::string&) copy constructor to initialize m_str.

What essentially gets done is:

```
// create a std::string object initialized with the c-string.
std::string rvalueString = std::string("all of the toppings");
// now we have a string to pass to DIYPizza's constructor.
DIYPizza dinner(rvalueString);
```

However - we're still only calling ONE *member function of Foo* at this point. The only way for more class members to be invoked is by calling them from whichever constructor is invoked.

```
class DinnerAtHome {
    void orderPizza();
    void drinkBeer();
    void watchTV(); // I was going with something more brazen, but...
public:
    DinnerAtHome() {
        orderPizza();
        drinkBeer();
        watchTV();
        drinkBeer();
        // arrival of pizza is handled elsewhere.
    }
};
```

Now when you construct a new DinnerAtHome, 5 member functions will be invoked: DinnerAtHome::DinnerAtHome() and the four member-function calls it makes.

Note: "new" is not a member function, it is a [global operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/).

IF the answer was "five" then either the interviewer was using a trick question or you missed some nuance of what was being asked.

Comment: lol. Unluckily I can't select this answer as best. Very creative methods names (never undervaluate the fact you need good names XD). Only bad point is "Foo"  (who am I to criticize when I use "foo/bar" all the ways) in the first 2 code snippets. upvote :)

Comment: @DarioOO Dang it - I couldn't resist :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I try overkill answer since no once already selected an answer:
When you create an object the constructor is called, this also involves a call to underlying constructors of members objects, if the object inherits from another object you need also to call constructors of base classes

```
class Foo: public Bar{

    std::vector<int> indices; //default constructor for indices is called

public:

    Foo(int a):Bar(a){ //you have to call constructor of Bar here
                       //else compiling error will occur
    }

};
```

Default constructor is called implicitly for objects that has it. When you create something with "new", first memory is allocated then object is constructed on top of that memory (placement new works in a similiar way, but the chunk of memory may be created explicity by the user elsewhere).

Note that in certain cases you don't know order of constructors calls:

CASE 1

```
Obj1* myobj= new Obj1 ( new Obj2, new Obj3( new Obj4) );
```

in this case you have no clues if Obj4 is created before or after Obj2 and if Obj3 is created before or after Obj2, simply the compiler will try to choose "an order" (that may vary depending on compiler and platform), also this is a highly unsafe code:
assume you get exception in Obj3 when Obj2 was already created, then Obj3 memory will never get deallocated (in that extreme case you may find usefull tools for those kinds of problems : [Hypodermic](https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic) / [Infectorpp](http://code.google.com/p/infectorpp/) )

[see also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355331/c-exception-safety-in-constructor)

CASE 2

static/global variables may be initialized in different orders, and you have to rely on specific compiler functions to declare a initialization order

for GCC:

```
void f __attribute__((constructor (N)));
```

---

also note that "Constructor" is not a "method" like others, infact you cannot save constructor in a std::function nor bind it with std::bind. The only way to save a constructor is to wrap it with a factory method.

well that should be 5 "things" as you mentioned in the interview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a class means you are calling constructor of that class. If constructor is not in your code than compiler will add the default constructor. YOu can override default constructor to perform some task on object creation.
For 
Example:
If you are creating a object of type Person

```
Person* objPerson = new Person();
```

It means you are calling Person() method(constructor) of that class.

```
class Person {
public:
   Person() {
       // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: ok thanks for the answer but apart from constructor what else are called.I was asked in an interview that there are five methods.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Grigore what do you mean sir..?

Comment: this looks close to Java, but not C++

Comment: than what happen in terms of c++

Comment: `Person objPerson = new Person();` is not valid C++

Comment: Sorry guys i have posted answer that is belongs to java but not c++.

Comment: @maruti You shouldn't have as question is tagged as C++ and it may mislead someone if you post java code (without saying first it's java).

Comment: ya i realized.thats of  mine big mistake

Answer (score 0):

When a new object is constructed, the constructor of the class is invoked to initialize non-static member variables of the class (if the class does not have any constructors, compiler assigns a an empty constructor for the class and invokes it). The constructor may invoke other functions (either library or user-defined functions), but that depends on the functions that programmer has invoked inside the constructor. Also, if the class is part of an inheritance hierarchy, appropriate constructor of base classes are called by compiler before the constructor of the class being instantiated (visit [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/constructor_destructor_ordering.html) for a brief explanation).

Answer (score 0):

When an object of a class is instantiated : memory required by the object of the class (depending on its data members) is allocated on the heap and  a reference to that memory location is stored by the object name. This individual data members at this memory location on the heap may or may not be initialized depending on the constructor called.